# Error in Infix to Postfix Conversion using linked lists

Tags: c++

I wrote a c++ program to convert an infix expression to postfix expression.
Whenever I run it, it seems to go into an infinite loop. 
I've used a stack to store the operators and parenthesis etc. and a queue to store the postfix expression itself.
The user enters the whole infix expression and the program takes one character at a time while the rest of the infix expression remains in the stdin stream.

I just couldn't figure out the mistake in this program, Please help!

Program Code:

```
 #include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
struct LIST
{
    char val;
    LIST* next;
};
LIST* start_stack=NULL;
LIST* start_post=NULL;
LIST* end_post=NULL;
LIST* np;


int check_char(char a)
{
    if(isalnum(a))
    return 1;//For operand

    else if(a=='^'||a=='*'||a=='/'||a=='+'||a=='-') //For operator
    {
    if(a=='^')
    return 21;
    else if(a=='*'||a=='/')
    return 22;
    else
    return 23;
    }
    else if(a=='('||a=='['||a=='{')//For openeing parenthesis
    return 3;
    else if(a==')'||a=='}'||a==']')
    return 4;
    else
return 0;

}
void push(LIST* push_element, int i=1)
{
    if(i==1)
    {
        if(start_stack==NULL)
        start_stack=push_element;
        else
        {
            LIST* temp;
            temp=start_stack;
            start_stack=np;
            start_stack->next=temp;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(start_post==NULL)
        start_post=end_post=np;
        else
            {
                end_post->next=np;
                end_post=np;
            }
    }
}

void pop(LIST* pop_element)
{
    LIST *temp;
    temp=pop_element;
    pop_element=pop_element->next;
    delete temp;
}



void Infix_to_Postfix()
{

     char a;
     cin>>a;
     while(a!='.')
     {
         if(check_char(a)==1)
         {
             np=new LIST;
             np->val=a;
             np->next=NULL;
             push(np,2);
         }
         else if(check_char(a)>20)
         {
             while(start_stack!=NULL&&check_char(start_stack->val)!=3)
             {
                 if(check_char(a)>=check_char(start_stack->val))
                 {
                      np=new LIST;
                      np->val=start_stack->val;
                      np->next=NULL;
                      push(np,2);
                      pop(start_stack);
                 }
             }
             np=new LIST;
             np->val=a;
             np->next=NULL;
             push(np);
         }
         else if(check_char(a)==3)
         {
             np=new LIST;
             np->val=a;
             np->next=NULL;
             push(np);
         }
         else if(check_char(a)==4)
         {
             while(start_stack!=NULL&&check_char(start_stack->val)!=3)
             {
                 np=new LIST;
                 np->val=start_stack->val;
                 np->next=NULL;
                 push(np,2);
                 pop(start_stack);
             }
             pop(start_stack);
         }
     cin>>a;
     }

     while(start_stack!=NULL)
     {
          np=new LIST;
          np->val=start_stack->val;
          np->next=NULL;
          push(np,2);
          pop(start_stack);
     }

     while(start_post!=NULL)
     {
         cout<<endl;
         cout<<start_post->val;
         start_post=start_post->next;
     }
}


int main()
{
    clrscr();
    Infix_to_Postfix();
    getch();
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: don't use magic numbers, i.e. `21`, `22`...

Comment: don't use ALLCAPS for anything but macros.

Comment: format your code with whitespaces  (e.g. around binary operators)

Comment: debug your code. Oh.. said that already.. Well, it's the most important one. **Debug** your code!.

Comment: You probably should add lots of printout statements to your code, saying what it's doing at each step. Run it on small inputs and then increasingly larger ones, and look at the printouts until you understand what's happening.

Comment: Why not use `std::stack`?  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack

Comment: Push only pushes it's argument of the stack is empty, otherwise it pushes np. Pop only modifies it's local copy of it's argument, not the variable in the calling function. Debugging would have found both these problems. You really need to learn how to debug. I often end up with lots of print statements, but at this stage, just single step and looking at how variables change will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue is in the function.

```
void pop(LIST* pop_element)
```

The value being popped works find, but it doesn't modify the sent in parameter.

So the line

```
 pop(start_stack);
```

Removes the memory start_stack, but doesn't change the pointer start_stack.
Creating a reference would fix this issue.

i.e.

```
void pop(LIST* & pop_element)
{
    LIST *temp;
    temp=pop_element;
    pop_element=pop_element->next;
    delete temp;
}
```

### How to find these errors

My debug environment used MSVC and a debug heap.  When the same memory was freed a second time, it broke in the debugger and was relatively easy to figure this problem.  For linux you could use valgrind, non MS compilers on windows Application Verifier would find this issue.

If you use a debugger single step through the code.  Look at the values of the variables, and check they are as you expect.

In this case (without a debug heap, I could have seen that the pointer `start_stack` was not changing value.

The code provided is an implementation of a list, a stack and using these together for the required infix to postfix conversion.

Try unit testing the list behavior separately from the larger problem.
Try unit testing the stack behavior separately from the larger problem.  The stack overflow requires the smallest verifiable code sample ([SO : MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).  This is to encourage you to deconstruct your problem to find the smallest piece of code which doesn't work.  This should also help to focus you on how to fix it.

When you are implementing stacks and queues, try comparing against the std::stack and std::queue behavior, again helping you to identify the unit which is failing.

Finally for stack overflow, a program which eats stdin is difficult for people to see what is going on.  Ensure you specify what input is required to cause the behavior, or provide a program which takes input from itself....

```
 void Old()
 {  
     int myVar;
     cin > myVar;
 }
 int main()
 {
      Old();
 }
```

should be

```
 void Old( std::istream & stm )
 {  
     int myVar;
     stm > myVar;
 }
 int main()
 {
      std::stringstream s( "123" ); // test value causes issue.
      Old(s );
 }
```